# Unable to remove Embedded Tomcat from Grails 3.0.7 Application war

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-3.0

I tried following the notes in the grails documentation and attempted to remove the embedded tomcat server when creating a war file for deployment.

However, even though in build.gradle I have :

```
...
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
...
```

The generated WAR file is of the same size as before amending `compile` to `provided` for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat.

While exploring the WAR file I am still seeing the following files:

spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.23.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar

The question is, why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

OK, it seems to work like this and it would be great if the Grails documentation was a little clearer on what's happening behind the scenes.

Scenario 1 : When creating a (production) war using `grails war` and `compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"` ...

Unzipping/exploding the war file, I see Tomcat is embedded within WEB-INF lib folder (5 or more jars) with all the other required application jars and there is also a folder org/springframework containing what looks to be the class files required to launch the embedded Tomcat server.

Scenario 2 : When creating a (production) war using `grails war` and `provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"` ...

The 5 or more Tomcat embedded jars are moved out of WEB-INF/lib and placed in WEB-INF/lib-provided.  The org/springframework folder and it's contents are not included either.

Testing on a local installation, you can drop this 'scenario 2' version of the war file into the Tomcat web apps directory and the application deploys without a hitch (the lib-provided folder and it's tomcat embed jars presumably being ignored).

Finally, there is a another version of the war file created : appname.war.original

This war doesn't have the WEB-INF/lib-provided nor the org/springframework folder and is smaller in size (of course).

This war also deploys correctly.

Why the tomcat embed jars are included in scenario 2 at all baffles me but there you go....

There is a discussion on it here too :

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-12078

In a way, the grails documentation is correct.  You remove the embedded tomcat server by adding provided

It just still bundles the jars into a folder named `lib-provided` for some reason.

Hope this helps any else pondering the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle, add the following:

```
springBoot {
    providedConfiguration = "provided"
}
```

Honestly, I don't understand the inner workings, but I had the very same problem and this is what provided (no pun intended) the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid that didn't work for me but I seem to have found the answer which I'll add below.

Comment: You're correct that my solution still includes the additional jars, but the war is now both a deployable war and also a runnable j(w)ar. That was what I wanted to achieve.

Have you tried to just leave out the whole spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency as you are not interested in a runnable war?

Comment: Hi Michael,  yes I tried leaving out the spring-boot-starter-tomcat entirely, but the application fails to compile as it can't firstly find the HttpServletRequest class....